# In TS i have a class extends. Can i call super.propertie and this.propertie and has different values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have the code:

```
  class Person {
  role: string
  constructor(public name: string){
   this.role = 'parent'; 
  }
  sayHello(): void{
    console.log(`I'm ${this.name}`)
  }
}

// victor.sayHello();

class User extends Person{
  role: string
  constructor(public name: string, public userId: string){
    super(name)
    this.role = 'son'
    console.log('Super name::>>', super.sayHello())
    console.log(this.role, super.role)
  }
  present(): void {
    console.log(`Im ${this.name} and my user id is ${this.userId} ${super.name}`)
  }
}
```

Can i call super.role and this.role? When i try to, super.role returns undefined. Why?

Comment: Why is role declared on both Person and User classes? I think that is the problem.

Comment: `role` isn't declared on the prototype. `super` can only retrieve properties/methods from the prototype.

Comment: There is only one `role` property in your code: on the instance. It does not live in the class (or on the class' prototype), unlike methods or getters/setters do. So there is no point in attempting to access two different `role` properties with different syntax.